# How can i get count of each month in current year SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I need to get count of rows per month in current year. I have SQL database with field reg_date where contains date in format `2018-10-10` (Year-Month-Date).
Look, i wrote this SQL request and have result:

```
SELECT distinct extract(month from reg_date) as Months, 
       COUNT(*) as RegCount 
FROM Orders 
GROUP BY Months
```

[image: Database result]

As you can see, i have all month and theirs counts. But i need data only from current year. How can i integrate this condition?

**Repeat:** I need the Count of rows per month in current year.

Thanks!

Comment: add a where condition ....

Comment: `WHERE YEAR(reg_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())`

Comment: Pretty sure you could use `MONTH(reg_date)` instead of extract as well

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks a lot :D

Comment: @RiggsFolly I would use `WHERE reg_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'` to be able to use index of reg_date (if any)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Distinct` usage is not required when you are doing `Group By`.
- We can use [`Month()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) and [`Year()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) functions to extract month and year out of a date, respectively.

In order to consider only the rows from current year, we can thus use:

```
WHERE YEAR(reg_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

However, using a function on a column in `Where` clause impedes the usage of Indexing (if defined) on `reg_date` column. So, we can rather use the following instead:

```
WHERE reg_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
```

In order to make it more generic (year number agnostic), we can do the following instead:

```
WHERE reg_date 
      BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) AND 
              LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 12-MONTH(NOW()) MONTH))
```

OR,

```
WHERE reg_date 
      BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) AND 
              MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), IF(MOD(YEAR(CURDATE()), 4), 365, 366))
```

Try the following query instead:

```
SELECT MONTH(reg_date) AS Months, 
       COUNT(*) AS RegCount 
FROM Orders 
WHERE reg_date 
      BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) AND 
              MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), IF(MOD(YEAR(CURDATE()), 4), 365, 366))
GROUP BY Months
```

Comment: @maximepihin never worked with it. But what is the question ? I can try to figure out.

Comment: Look, i have 2 requests: `Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT MONTH(reg_date) AS Months, COUNT(*) AS RegCount FROM users WHERE YEAR(reg_date) = YEAR(NOW()) ORDER BY Months')->queryAll();` -> there are some data, but in `$this->find()->select(['MONTH(reg_date) AS Months', 'COUNT(*) AS RegCount'])->where(['YEAR(reg_date)' => 'YEAR(NOW())'])->groupBy('Months')->all();` -> nothing... Why? Request from Model Users!

Comment: @maximepihin hmm - both look same though. Sorry, no idea why it could be. Maybe there is some small trick. You may ask the SO community with a new question on it.